# Error:-(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am getting the following error while debugging my Windows Form Application for generating an excel sheet:

```
Application is Busy.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER)).
```

I have gone thoroughly through the code and have not found any errors. An internet search suggests the problem is in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.dll`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You are doing it wrong.  We can't see you doing it wrong.  As long as you don't want to show us your code, you'll have to keep googling until you find something that talks about IMessageFilter or turning off background recalculation.  It has nothing to do with the interop dll.

Comment: Have you tried an [OLE message filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms228772(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)?

Answer (score 4):

This problem usually happens when the Office application like Excel is waiting in some modal dialog or editing formula is active and the app is not in a state to accept any commands.

Try to play with visibility of Excel while you execute your automation tasks:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();                
ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = true;
ExcelApp.Visible = true;
ExcelApp.Interactive = true;
ExcelApp.IgnoreRemoteRequests = false;
```

Of course after you find out what the problem is, your automation will be faster with:

```
ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
ExcelApp.Visible = false;
```